# Use the same apple app store certificate for multiple apps

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

Hi I have multiple apps,
and wondered if i am going to need to create an app store certificate for each of the apps separate.
The real problem is that all those certificates have the same name and I won't be able in the future to know which certificate belongs to which app.

looking for your answers,
Matan

Comment: Certificate or provisioning profile ?

Comment: App store certificate

Comment: You need one certificate, why are you creating multiple certificates ? One certificate and multiple provisioning profile, that's the good way to opt.

Answer (score 0):

a certificate can sign multiple applications, Apple said no more than 50, no problem, no need to distinguish